# grouping some fields and selecting some of them in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below. I obtained this table with grouping some fields.

```
739033  007607000176    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000176    ELTN    007607000176    ELTN    43494   24  82860   580360
753281  007607000176    23.01.2014 13:13:38 007607000176    ELTN    007607000176    ELTN    43494   24  82860   580360
738084  007607000390    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000390    PRTG    007607000390    BASC    18368   14  70865   191623
752332  007607000390    23.01.2014 13:13:38 007607000390    PRTG    007607000390    BASC    18368   14  70865   191623
738238  007607000574    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000574    PRTG    007607000574    PRTG    18368   14  67456   297456
752486  007607000574    23.01.2014 13:13:38 007607000574    PRTG    007607000574    PRTG    18368   14  67456   297456
738508  007607000655    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000655    BASC    007607000655    PRTG    805 1   10520   283020
752756  007607000655    23.01.2014 13:13:38 007607000655    BASC    007607000655    PRTG    805 1   10520   283020
432213  007607000670    14.05.2011 00:12:31 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    40506   25  163933  903433
432460  007607000670    15.05.2011 00:12:35 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    40506   25  163933  903433
432660  007607000670    16.05.2011 00:12:37 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    40506   25  163933  903433
738083  007607000670    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    78370   46  109520  1199020
752331  007607000670    23.01.2014 13:13:38 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    78370   46  109520  1199020
433177  007607000670    18.05.2011 00:12:40 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    41506   26  95183   904683
433428  007607000670    19.05.2011 00:12:42 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    41506   26  95183   904683
433928  007607000670    21.05.2011 00:12:49 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    44324   28  101706  911206
434420  007607000670    23.05.2011 00:12:55 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    44324   28  101706  911206
434156  007607000670    22.05.2011 00:12:50 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    44324   28  101706  911206
```

I want to select one of them that has the same id.(second column).How can I do ?

**EDIT**
This is what I want :

```
 739033 007607000176    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000176    ELTN    007607000176    ELTN    43494   24  82860   580360
 738084 007607000390    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000390    PRTG    007607000390    BASC    18368   14  70865   191623
 738083 007607000670    23.01.2014 13:10:53 007607000670    ELTN    007607000670    ELTN    78370   46  109520  1199020
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your your expected output for the given data?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why those 3 rows and not any of the others with duplicate values in the second column (i.e. `007607000655` or `007607000574`)?

Comment: They have to be either. I wrote just three.

Comment: Also, why that particular row starting with `738083  007607000670    23.01.2014 13:10:53` - why not the row `432213  007607000670    14.05.2011 00:12:31` which is earlier in your list and is earlier chronologically?

Comment: You are right. I want it to be chronologically first one .

Comment: @MT0 What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`.  For instance, if the third column where `datetime`, then the following gets the most recent row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: And I used group by statement in inner query.@Gordon Linoff

Comment: @AknKplnoglu . . . I see no material change to the question.  This answer still seems to be the right approach for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include in your query count(1) and group by all other columns. Also add having count1) > 1 in your query. Please take a look at the sample:

```
with src as (
  select '1' as id,'s1' as descr from dual
  union all
  select '1','s1' from dual
  union all
  select '2','s2' from dual
)
select id,descr,count(*) from src group by id,descr
having count(*) > 1
```